# Verificacion de número y letras con KeyPressed JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing

He estado buscando la forma de que en el JTextField se limite a aceptar solo 3 caracteres numéricos.
Sin embargo al ejecutar cada vez que encuentra un numero lo coloca doble.

Mi código:

```java
private void txtserialKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    if (txtserial.getText().length() < 3) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() >= 48 && evt.getKeyCode() <= 57) {
            txtserial.setText(txtserial.getText() + String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar()));
        }
    }
}
```

> Entrada : 2

> Salida: 22

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que ver con el evento. Resulta ser que el evento KeyPressed marca cuando apenas presionas el botón y lo dejes presionado....así sea un segundo el evento registrara varias veces el carácter.....usa mejor el evento que se activa cuando sueltas el botón....keyReleased

Comment: Aún sigue aceptando las letras a pesar de la restriccion de solo números

Comment: De tu codigo elimina el Switch y prueba solo con el condicional if.

Comment: Gracias por la orientación

Answer (score 1):

Esta el componente `JFormattedTextField` que puede ser de mucha utilidad para este caso, suponiendo:

```
entrada = new JFormattedTextField( getNumFormat() );
```

Luego un pequeño hack con el formato:

```
private MaskFormatter getNumFormat() {
  MaskFormatter MF = null;

  try {
    MF = new MaskFormatter( "###" ); //Tres digitos.
  } catch( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return MF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que seria mejor validarlo cuando la tecla ya esta ntypeada ya que en el eventro preset si la mantiene oprimida dejaria pasar... y lo otro es con el metodo consume.
intenta esto haber.

```
private void txtserialKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    if (txtserial.getText().length()<3) {
        if (evt.getKeyCode()>=48 && evt.getKeyCode()<=57) {
                txtserial.setText(txtserial.getText()+String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar()));
            }else{
               consume(evt);//anule ewl evente
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Continua aceptando letras

Comment: perdon me equivoque, es evt.consume();

Comment: si no da entonces prueba capturando el evento evt.getKeyChar()